# Compare branches in EGit?

Tags: eclipse, branch, egit

I want to see all differences between two branches of a repo, not just differences in one file. Can I get both to appear simultaneously in History view so I can do "Compare with each other", or is there some other way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set your project at one of the branches, right click on root project directory

> Compare With -> Branch,Tag or Reference

Then pick the other branch. Result will be shown on *Synchronize* view

[image]